# Orange Test & Score hanging at 0% for hours

Tags: orange

I'm using Orange to run image classification using the corresponding plugin.

I'm trying to use the dataset below, training 196 classes on ~16,000 images.
https://ai.stanford.edu/~jkrause/cars/car_dataset.html

Following the standard tutorial for this, I have exactly the same format for my workflow.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lvgx62a8XQk&t=92s

After loading in the photos, the embedding takes place. It uses up all 16GB of my RAM for a long while but supposedly completes. I cannot view any of these embeds using the Data Table widget.

It moves onto Test & Score, which hangs at 0%. It has been hanging like this for a number of hours now.

Does anyone know what's happening here? Did I break the capacity of Orange? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that when working with large datasets, even with 16GB+ RAM and 4GHz+ CPU, Orange uses up virtually all RAM and will take half a day to process the necessary data. The Test&Score just completed.

Comment: Image embedding sends all images onto a remote server. This might take some time too. https://orange3-imageanalytics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/widgets/imageembedding.html